# Extract and manipulate dict data to check certificates

Tags: python, jquery, dictionary, ansible

I struggle on a regular basis with data manipulation in Ansible. I'm not very familiar with Python and dict objects. I found an example that sums up a lot of my misunderstandings.

I would like to verify a list of certificates. In found an example for a single domain in the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/crypto/x509_certificate_module.html#ansible-collections-community-crypto-x509-certificate-module), I'm just trying to loop over several domain names.

Certs are stored in a folder:

```
certs/
├── domain.com
│   ├── domain.com.pem
│   └── domain.com.key
└── domain.org
    ├── domain.org.key
    └── domain.org.pem
```

My playbook is as follow:

```yaml
---
- name: "check certs"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    domain_names:
      - domain.com
      - domain.org
    certs_folder: certs
  tasks: 
    - name: Get certificate information
      community.crypto.x509_certificate_info:
        path: "{{ certs_folder }}/{{ item }}/{{ item }}.pem"
        # for valid_at, invalid_at and valid_in
      register: result_certs
      loop: "{{ domain_names }}"
      failed_when: 0

    - name: Get private key information
      community.crypto.openssl_privatekey_info:
        path: "{{ certs_folder }}/{{ item }}/{{ item }}.key"
      register: result_privatekey
      loop: "{{ domain_names }}"
      failed_when: 0

    - name: Check cert and key match << DOES NOT WORK >>>
      assert: 
        that:
          - result_certs[ {{ item }} ].public_key == result_privatekey[ {{ item }} ].public_key
          # - ... other checks ...
          - not result[ {{ item }} ].expired
      loop: "{{ domain_names }}"
```

So I get two variables `result_certs` and `result_privatekey`, each has a element `result` which is , if  I understand correctly, an array of dicts:

```json
"result_certs": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "expired": false,
                "item": "domain.org",
                "public_key": "<<PUBLIC KEY>>"
            },
            {
                "expired": false,
                "item": "domain.com",
                "public_key": "<<PUBLIC KEY>>"
            }
        ],
        "skipped": false
    }
```

```json
"result_privatekey": {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "results": [
    {
        "item": "domain.org",
        "public_key": "<< PUBLIC KEY >>"
    },
    {
        "item": "domain.com",
        "public_key": "<< PUBLIC KEY >>"
    }
    ],
    "skipped": false
}
```

How can I refer to each of the dicts elements like `result_privatekey.results[the dict where item ='domain.org'].public_key` in the `assert` task?

I feel like I'm missing something, or a documentation page to make it clear to me. I noticed that I particularly struggle with arrays of dicts, and I run into those objects quite often...

I found those resources useful, but not sufficient to get this job done:

- https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html
- https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/

EDIT:
`map` and `selectattr` are the filters required to solve this problem, although the documentation (including the [official ansible doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html)) is not that clear to me... This is very useful to get many tutorial examples on those two filters if one is struggling as I do.

Comment: See [Manipulating data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html#manipulating-data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the simplified data for testing

```yaml
  result_certs:
    changed: false
    msg: All items completed
    results:
      - expired: false
        item: domain.org
        public_key: <<PUBLIC KEY domain.org>>
      - expired: false
        item: domain.com
        public_key: <<PUBLIC KEY domain.com>>
    skipped: false

  result_privatekey:
    changed: false
    msg: All items completed
    results:
      - item: domain.org
        public_key: <<PUBLIC KEY domain.org>>
      - item: domain.com
        public_key: <<PUBLIC KEY domain.com>>
    skipped: false
```

Declare the list of the domains

```yaml
  domains: "{{ result_certs.results|
               map(attribute='item')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  domains:
  - domain.org
  - domain.com
```

---

Q: ***"How can I refer to each dictionary element?"***

A: *select* the item(s) and map the attribute

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: pk
      loop: "{{ domains }}"
      vars:
        pk: "{{ result_privatekey.results|
                selectattr('item', '==', item)|
                map(attribute='public_key')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=domain.org) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: domain.org
  pk:
  - <<PUBLIC KEY domain.org>>
ok: [localhost] => (item=domain.com) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: domain.com
  pk:
  - <<PUBLIC KEY domain.com>>
```

In the same way, you can compare the keys in the loop

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ pk1 }} == {{ pk2 }}: {{ pk1 == pk2 }}"
      loop: "{{ domains }}"
      vars:
        pk1: "{{ result_privatekey.results|
                 selectattr('item', '==', item)|
                 map(attribute='public_key')|first }}"
        pk2: "{{ result_certs.results|
                 selectattr('item', '==', item)|
                 map(attribute='public_key')|first }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=domain.org) => 
  msg: '<<PUBLIC KEY domain.org>> == <<PUBLIC KEY domain.org>>: True'
ok: [localhost] => (item=domain.com) => 
  msg: '<<PUBLIC KEY domain.com>> == <<PUBLIC KEY domain.com>>: True'
```

Q: ***"Extract and manipulate dict data to check certificates."***

A: There are many options:

1. For example, create a unique list of all public keys

```yaml
  pkeys: "{{ result_certs.results|
             zip(result_privatekey.results)|
             map('map', attribute='public_key')|
             map('unique')|flatten }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  pkeys:
  - <<PUBLIC KEY domain.org>>
  - <<PUBLIC KEY domain.com>>
```

To find the redundant keys compare the lists *pkeys* and *domains*. Compare the lengths to briefly find out if there are any

```yaml
  pkeys|length == domains|length
```

To find the expired domains declare variables

```yaml
  expired: "{{ result_certs.results|
               map(attribute='expired')|list }}"
  expired_domains: "{{ result_certs.results|
                       selectattr('expired')|
                       map(attribute='item')|list }}"
```

give

```yaml
  expired:
  - false
  - false

  expired_domains: []
```

Then the *assert* task should look like

```yaml
    - assert:
        that:
          - expired is not any
          - pkeys|length == domains|length
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    result_certs:
      changed: false
      msg: All items completed
      results:
      - expired: false
        item: domain.org
        public_key: <<PUBLIC KEY domain.org>>
      - expired: false
        item: domain.com
        public_key: <<PUBLIC KEY domain.com>>
      skipped: false

    result_privatekey:
      changed: false
      msg: All items completed
      results:
      - item: domain.org
        public_key: <<PUBLIC KEY domain.org>>
      - item: domain.com
        public_key: <<PUBLIC KEY domain.com>>
      skipped: false

    domains: "{{ result_certs.results|
                 map(attribute='item')|list }}"
    pkeys: "{{ result_certs.results|
               zip(result_privatekey.results)|
               map('map', attribute='public_key')|
               map('unique')|flatten }}"
    expired: "{{ result_certs.results|
                 map(attribute='expired')|list }}"
    expired_domains: "{{ result_certs.results|
                         selectattr('expired')|
                         map(attribute='item')|list }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: domains

    - debug:
        var: pkeys

    # How can I refer to each of the dicts elements?
    - debug:
        var: pk
      loop: "{{ domains }}"
      vars:
        pk: "{{ result_privatekey.results|
                selectattr('item', '==', item)|
                map(attribute='public_key')|list }}"

    # How can I compare private keys?
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ pk1 }} == {{ pk2 }}: {{ pk1 == pk2 }}"
      loop: "{{ domains }}"
      vars:
        pk1: "{{ result_privatekey.results|
                 selectattr('item', '==', item)|
                 map(attribute='public_key')|first }}"
        pk2: "{{ result_certs.results|
                 selectattr('item', '==', item)|
                 map(attribute='public_key')|first }}"
    - debug:
        var: expired
    - debug:
        var: expired_domains

    - assert:
        that:
          - expired is not any
          - pkeys|length == domains|length
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  domains:
  - domain.org
  - domain.com

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  pkeys:
  - <<PUBLIC KEY domain.org>>
  - <<PUBLIC KEY domain.com>>

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=domain.org) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: domain.org
  pk:
  - <<PUBLIC KEY domain.org>>
ok: [localhost] => (item=domain.com) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: domain.com
  pk:
  - <<PUBLIC KEY domain.com>>

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=domain.org) => 
  msg: '<<PUBLIC KEY domain.org>> == <<PUBLIC KEY domain.org>>: True'
ok: [localhost] => (item=domain.com) => 
  msg: '<<PUBLIC KEY domain.com>> == <<PUBLIC KEY domain.com>>: True'

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  expired:
  - false
  - false

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  expired_domains: []

TASK [assert] ********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=7    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

2. The next option is to create a structure for this purpose. For example, put into the lists the attributes which might have different values (i.e. *public_key* in this case). Merge the dictionaries by the domain and append unique attributes. Declare the variables

```yaml
  l1: "{{ result_certs.results|json_query('[].{item: item,
                                               expired: expired,
                                               pk: [public_key]}') }}"
  l2: "{{ result_privatekey.results|json_query('[].{item: item,
                                                    pk: [public_key]}') }}"
  lm: "{{ [l1, l2]|community.general.lists_mergeby('item', 
                                                    list_merge='append_rp') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  lm:
  - expired: false
    item: domain.com
    pk:
    - <<PUBLIC KEY domain.com>>
  - expired: false
    item: domain.org
    pk:
    - <<PUBLIC KEY domain.org>>
```

Use this structure to compare any attributes. For example, declare

```yaml
  exprd: "{{ lm|map(attribute='expired')|list }}"
  pkeys: "{{ lm|map(attribute='pk')|
                map('length')|sum }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  exprd:
  - false
  - false

  pkeys: '2'
```

Then, use it in the conditions

```yaml
    - assert:
        that:
          - exprd is not any
          - pkeys|int == lm|length
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    result_certs:
      changed: false
      msg: All items completed
      results:
      - expired: false
        item: domain.org
        public_key: <<PUBLIC KEY domain.org>>
      - expired: false
        item: domain.com
        public_key: <<PUBLIC KEY domain.com>>
      skipped: false

    result_privatekey:
      changed: false
      msg: All items completed
      results:
      - item: domain.org
        public_key: <<PUBLIC KEY domain.org>>
      - item: domain.com
        public_key: <<PUBLIC KEY domain.com>>
      skipped: false


    l1: "{{ result_certs.results|json_query('[].{item: item,
                                                 expired: expired,
                                                 pk: [public_key]}') }}"
    l2: "{{ result_privatekey.results|json_query('[].{item: item,
                                                      pk: [public_key]}') }}"
    lm: "{{ [l1, l2]|
            community.general.lists_mergeby('item',
                                            list_merge='append_rp') }}"

    exprd: "{{ lm|map(attribute='expired')|list }}"
    pkeys: "{{ lm|map(attribute='pk')|
                  map('length')|sum }}"
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: l1
    - debug:
        var: l2
    - debug:
        var: lm
    - debug:
        var: exprd
    - debug:
        var: pkeys

    - assert:
        that:
          - exprd is not any
          - pkeys|int == lm|length
```

---

3. In addition to the structure created in option 2) create dictionaries to test the attributes selectively. For example,

```yaml
  domain_exprd: "{{ lm|items2dict(key_name='item', value_name='expired') }}"
  domain_pkeys: "{{ lm|items2dict(key_name='item', value_name='pk') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  domain_exprd:
    domain.com: false
    domain.org: false

  domain_pkeys:
    domain.com:
    - <<PUBLIC KEY domain.com>>
    domain.org:
    - <<PUBLIC KEY domain.org>>
```

Answer (score 2):

From what you are showing — but you might have more conditions that needs it — I wouldn't loop on the `domain_names` in your assertion task, I would rather loop on `result_certs`.

From there on, you can select the corresponding private key thanks to the [`selectattr` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr).

So, your assertion would become:

```yaml
- assert: 
    that:
      - >-
          item.public_key == (
            result_privatekey.results 
              | selectattr('item', '==', item.item) 
              | first
          ).public_key
      # - ... other checks ...
      - not item.expired
  loop: "{{ result_certs.results }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Is there a way to handle a failure (if the .pem file does not exist for instance, so the public_key entry does not exist) keeping that looping structure?

Comment: Sure, you can just compare the length of the two lists in the assert, so: `- domain_names | length == result_certs.results | length`.